# IOIO open accessory connection upon non-activity base

Tags: android, accessory

I did a small android program what works well if usb debugging is on. This program will be as a lib for B4A. I would like if it do work without usb debugging for higher version of android, i.e > 4.2, but I have an exactly 4.2 phone where I can test it and when I switch off the debugging mode the program can't connect. In the same phone the official Helloioio program can work in open accessory mode (as mine should be too), so the problem in this case surely not device dependant. What is the correct connection sequence for android open accessory connection for IOIO? 
This is the connection part of my code:

```
            BA.Log("IOIOConnectionRegistry.addBootstraps");
            IOIOConnectionRegistry.addBootstraps(new String[]{
                    "ioio.lib.android.accessory.AccessoryConnectionBootstrap",
                    "ioio.lib.impl.SocketIOIOConnectionBootstrap",
                    "ioio.lib.android.device.DeviceConnectionBootstrap",
                    "ioio.lib.android.bluetooth.BluetoothIOIOConnectionBootstrap"
            });        
            BA.Log("IOIOFactory.create");
            m_ioio_thread = IOIOFactory.create();

            BA.Log("waitForConnect");
            SystemClock.sleep(50L);
            m_ioio_thread.waitForConnect();
            BA.Log("Connected");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I didn't compile the iOIOLibAccessory yet, but it isn't my routine job so I have to dig how to do it with eclipse.

Comment: I did it! I had to make a register/unregister eventreceiver to work.